# Can I change the value of PHP variables in CSS hover selection?

Tags: php, html, css, web

everyone. I have a problem using CSS and PHP.
Here is the code:

```
.book {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-image: url(outside2.png);
    position: absolute;
    left: 557px;
    top: 70px;
}

.book:hover > .right {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay:0s;
    <?php $pos = 1 ?>
}

.right {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(r2.png);
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: -50px;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition:visibility 0s linear 0.2s,opacity 0.2s linear;
}
```

I want the variable `$pos`'s value change to `1` when users move their mouse on the div.

But `$pos` always be `1` no matter where my mouse is.

Do I use the wrong way to design this website?

Comment: you can not do this. you can't mix css / php codes.

Comment: you will have to post using ajax of some sort

Comment: Once your CSS is on the clients browser, your PHP variable doesn't "exist" any more. Once the PHP code has served the page to the client you can not change it's original values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options. One is to change the value with javascript and then submit it with AJAX. The other one is to change the value with javascript in a hidden field and then submit it with the form.